# How to copy the data in old col to new col with only unique values?

Tags: django, django-models, django-migrations

I'm trying to create a new unique field called `last_name_unique`. I need to copy the data from `last_name` to `last_name_unique`. The new field can be nullable so we can add null for the repeated values.

For example, if there are two last names with value "Junior", under the `last_name_unique` there will be one value "Junior" and then null for the other "Junior" value. The first "Junior" value should be saved and the second one should be saved as null.

```
from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

Any idea how to achieve this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

As I know so far, it would be a good approach to implement signals:

your_app/models.py

```
class Person(models.Model):
    ...
    last_name_unique = models.CharField(max_length=30, default=None, null=True)
```

your_app/apps.py

```
from django.apps import AppConfig

class YourAppConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'  # if your Django version uses it
    name = 'your_app'

    def ready(self):
        import your_app.signals
```

your_app/signals.py

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from your_app.models import Person


@receiver(post_save, sender=Person)
def add_last_name_unique(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        if not Person.objects.filter(last_name=instance.last_name):
            instance.last_name_unique = instance.last_name
            instance.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the default value of last_name_unique to null

```
last_name_unique = models.CharField(max_length=30,default=None)
```

and after that you can run a code something like this:

```
q=mymodel.objects.all()
for e in q:
    if not len(q.filter(last_name=e.last_name))>=2:
                e.last_name_unique=e.last_name
                e.save()
```

The above code will copy all unique last names, now you haven't been told which object has to save 'junior' as unique_last_name (i.e the latest saved one or the other one) if there are 2 or more fields with the last name 'junior'.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I should be able to add this as a data migration, shouldn't I? The first row with "junior" should be saved as unique_last_name. Yeah, the tricky part for me to save the first non-unique value and then save the second "junior" value as null for unique_last_name.

Comment: It will be easier if you explain for what purpose you are creating unique_last_name field.

Comment: I'm trying to have a column with only unique last names. The below code worked for me. Thanks! 

``` 
Person = apps.get_model("app", "Person") unique_last_names = set() for last_name in Person.objects.all(): if last_name.last_name in unique_last_names: last_name.last_name_unique = None else: last_name.last_name_unique = last_name.last_name unique_last_names.add(last_name.last_name) last_name.save() ```